# Authenticating to Microsoft Dynamics/Azure AD using username and password in .net 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics

I'm new to trying to access the Microsoft Dynamics API and I'm working my way through the tutorial here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/quick-start-console-app-csharp.  The tutorial works great, but only in .net 4.6.2 and we are on .net 5.0.  For the life of me I cannot find an example of how to replicate this functionality in .net 5.0.  Specifically, the section of code here

```
var authParameters = AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(new Uri(webApiUrl)).Result;
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authParameters.Authority, false);
var authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(url, clientId, userCredential);
```

throws an error on the AcquireToken method.  Does anyone know how to login to Azure AD using a username and password in .net 5.0 as shown in this example?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to switch your code to use [MSAL.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-migration-confidential-client) (from ADAL.NET used in example).
Here is tutorial (not mine) specifically addressing acquiring tokens for Microsoft Dynamics API using MSAL library:
https://medium.com/capgemini-microsoft-team/access-tokens-for-dynamics-365-using-microsoft-authentication-library-2b16c9f794b

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, the tutorial in 4.6.2 uses a username and password combination to authenticate where this example uses a clientid and clientsecret.  I'm looking for a way to utilize username and password in .net 5.0 as well, which is what I can't find an example of.

Comment: It looks like using username and password is not recommended, but still possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#usernamepassword